# Data Loader error- (ID: value not of required type: 425.0.)

Tags: data-loader, import, data-types, text

[image]I'm trying to import a file with Data Loader into a Standard object and I get the errors as follow:

> ID: value not of required type: 425.0.

The Data Type is TEXT in salesforce. 
In the CSV import file the Column type is General and it contains numbers. I would like to import the numbers in a text field but it's adding .0 at the end of the number.
How can I fix this issue? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is adding"? What is "it"?

Comment: Can you add first few rows in the question, by scrambling personal details if they exists?

Comment: change the format of the csv column to Number then set decimals to 0; then save CSV file. Check file in a text editor that the trailing `.0` is removed before data loader step

Comment: Hi all,
I have added the picture for reference. 
The problem is I'm trying to insert the ID field into Salesforce( text) Data type and it is trowing error.

Answer (score 0):

Put a single quote (') character in front of the numbers in excel. This will make the number into a string.